# Why is there a slight lag between native apps and "desktop" apps?

Tags: responsive-design

So I'm not really sure how to explain this but I will try my best.

I created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xghar755/2/

As you quickly hover over each text, you can see that the background color changes. This is just a simple div with a css hover property. Here is the kicker though, go to your address bar and type in any letter and you get a drop down of items, like so.

[image]

Now, quickly hover your mouse over the items in the dropdown. And then go back to the jsfiddle and hover your mouse over its items. You can tell that the chrome versions` background color feels **more responsive**. It's *rarely* noticable, but I can tell.  Why is that?

Is this because Chrome's a Native application that doesn't rely on `CSS` or the `DOM`? If so, does this mean that native apps are generally more responsive in user interface applications? Thanks ~

Comment: I cannot really tell the difference, I'd actually be willing to bet it's a psychological thing based on how drastic the white/yellow switch in your demo is vs. the white/alice blue in google. the smaller the leap the quicker it appears to change.

Comment: @DasBeasto Good catch, I just tried it with a light [blue](https://jsfiddle.net/xghar755/3/) and it actually does seem just as fast. Interesting..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds more like a technical question that would be better in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is a software program running on your device. jsfiddle is, in part, a program that communicates with Chrome via the internet. Each transaction between the browser and jsfiddle takes tens of milliseconds, perhaps hundreds, and there can be a multitude of back and forth operations to serve one page and its in-betweens. In addition, Chrome is written in a language that runs in your machines native processing language while communication with jsfiddle is all interpreted by Chrome first, not to mention some processing is done on the jsfiddle server before being sent to your browser.

tl,dr; Programs running on your computer can do things a lot faster if they don't have to communicate with other programs over the internet.